# Why is the same code so much slower in my BackGroundWorker thread than in my GUI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance, backgroundworker

I am trying to create a c# WinForms application that searches and highlights text in a RichTextBox. I have created two search methods: one that runs in the GUI thread and one that runs in a BackGroundWorker. The logic in both methods is essentially identical. However, the code in the BGW runs considerably slower.

Please see the results below:

0.25MB Text file searching a common keyword: GUI: 2.9s - BGW: 7.0s
1MB Text file searching a common keyword: GUI:14.1s - BGW:71.4s
5MB Text file searching a common keyword: GUI:172s - BGW:1545s

It seems strange to me that the relationship between the time taken for the two methods is not liner with respect to search size.

The application will be used for searching files up to 10MB in size so it is important this is fast. I wanted to use a background worker so the user could see progress and continue reading the file while the search is being performed.

Please see the code for the two methods below:

```
    // background search thread
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the BackgroundWorker that raised this event.
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        RichTextBox results = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.Rtf = e.Argument as string;  //recive text to be searched

        int hits = 0; // track number of hits
        int pos = 0;  // track position in rtb
        int i = 0;    // trach current line number for progress report

        string lowerT = searchTerm.ToLowerInvariant();
        string lowerl = "";
        int n = 0;
        int len = searchTerm.Length;

        foreach (string l in rtb.Lines)
        {
            lowerl = l.ToLowerInvariant();
            n = lowerl.IndexOf(lowerT);
            if (n > -1)
            {
                while (n > -1)   //if found sterm highlight instances
                {
                    hits++;     //incriment hits

                    //hilight term
                    rtb.SelectionStart = pos + n;
                    rtb.SelectionLength = len;
                    rtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black;

                    //find next
                    n = lowerl.IndexOf(lowerT, n + len);
                }
                searchRes.Add(pos); // add positon of hit to results list

                //add rtb formatted text to results rtb
                rtb.SelectionStart = pos;
                rtb.SelectionLength = l.Length;
                results.SelectedRtf = rtb.SelectedRtf;
                results.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

            }
            pos += l.Length + 1; //incriment position

            //worker.ReportProgress(++i);
        }
        string[] res = {rtb.Rtf,results.Rtf,hits.ToString()};
        e.Result = res;
    }

    // old non threaded search method
    public void OldSearch(string sTerm)
    {
        int hits = 0; // track number of hits
        int pos = 0;  // track position in rtb
        int oldPos = richTextBox1.SelectionStart; //save current positin in rtb
        int oldLen = richTextBox1.SelectionLength;

        string lowerT = sTerm.ToLowerInvariant();

        sTime = 0;
        System.Threading.Timer tmr = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(TimerTask), null, 0, 100);

        if (sTerm.Length > 0)
        {
            //clear old search
            ReloadFile();
            richTextBox4.Clear();
            searchRes = new List<int>();

            //open results pane
            label1.Text = "Searching for \"" + sTerm + "\"...";
            splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = false;

            frmFind.Focus();
            frmFind.ShowProgress(true);

            foreach (string l in richTextBox1.Lines)
            {
                string lowerl = l.ToLowerInvariant();
                int n = lowerl.IndexOf(lowerT);
                if (n > -1)
                {
                    while (n > -1)   //if found sterm highlight instances
                    {
                        hits++;     //incriment hits
                        //hilight term
                        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = pos + n;
                        richTextBox1.SelectionLength = sTerm.Length;
                        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
                        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
                        //find next
                        n = lowerl.IndexOf(lowerT, n + sTerm.Length);
                    }
                    searchRes.Add(pos);
                    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = pos;
                    richTextBox1.SelectionLength = l.Length;
                    richTextBox4.SelectedRtf = richTextBox1.SelectedRtf;
                    richTextBox4.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                }
                pos += l.Length + 1; //incriment position
            }

            tmr.Dispose();

            float time = (float)sTime / 10;

            label1.Text = "Search for \"" + sTerm + "\": Found " + hits + " instances in " + time + " seconds.";
            richTextBox4.SelectionStart = 0;
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = oldPos;
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = oldLen;
            richTextBox1.Focus();
            frmFind.ShowProgress(false);
        }
    }
```

NOTES:

- I know that the RTB class has its own find method but found this to be considerably slower than my own method.
- I have read a number of threads regarding BGW performance and most seem to site the use of Invoke methods as the cause but I am using none.
- I understand the use of multiple threads will make it run slower but was not expecting this much difference.
- The problem is not with `ReportProgress` i have commented this line out. The reason i'm doing it this way rather than as a percentage is the calculation to work out the percentage made a big difference. It is actually faster this way
- This [link](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/using-richtextbox-thread-t1402964.html) provided by another user describes how I am using my RTB in a non GUI thread. It seems to suggest it shouldn't be a problem but will incur more overheads as it will cause the creation of a message queue. I'm not sure if this will be affecting the performance of the code within my foreach loop. Any comments on the matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the priority of the background thread is set too low? Also "essentially identical code" is not identical code.

Comment: @GCaiazzo Thanks for the comment. I tried setting the priority like this: `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.High;` but it didn't seem to make a difference. (I understand that this is a bad idea, as the thread is pooled. I Just did it as a test). When I said essentially identical I was referring to the logic in the foreach loop. Which is the same. I think ^^

Comment: The code I'm looking at is actually a Bad Thing(tm).  The first problem is that you're creating a `Control` (`RichTextBox`) on a background thread.  As a rule of thumb, ONLY create a Control on the main UI thread.  When you create a `Control` on a background thread, you're doing a _ton_ of crap in the background that should _not_ be done on a background thread.  Instead, pass a string to your background thread and have your background thread return highlighting indices so that your foreground thread can highlight the blocks of text the background thread found.

Comment: Keep in mind the UI isn't going to update much faster than every 20ms (about 60 times a second)--even if it did, why would you want to?  So, if you're in a background worker upgrading progress every couple of ms, you're spending a lot of time marshalling data into the UI thread--which isn't free.  You could try updating data as fast as you can in the background worker then have a UI Timer thread getting the data a few times a second--which might reduce the amount of marshalling.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that generally slows Winforms down is syncing with the UI thread. If ReportProgress does that (I don't know but I'm guessing it has to) and you call it too often (say 100-1000 times a second or more) it will slow everything to a grinding halt due to the various blocking issues that will occur.

Try removing whatever interaction between the UI and background thread you have and if that helps, reinstate the interaction but let it happen much less often, like 1-100 times a second.

Also, I'm not sure but if you're passing a reference to a control object, it might still be owned by the UI thread and each interaction with it from another thread could also cause syncing issues (and interaction with an actual forms control would throw an exception).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried what you suggested but unfortunately the performance is not really improved. I removed all references to GUI thread objects within the loop (`worker.ReportProgress()` and `searchRes.Add()`). This is what i am passing to the thread `string parsedText = richTextBox1.Rtf; backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(parsedText);` `parsedText` is a global variable of my `Form1` object.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure..., but every time you call the setter on SelectedRtf, a whole lot of stuff happens, including getting a unicode encoding of the string, writing it to a buffer and then a whole lot of windows messages are sent.

So firstly, if you can redesign the algorithm to do as much as possible without accessing the RTF search box and then batch up the highlighting, you'll probably improve performance.

As to the why it's slower... the RTF boxes are created on a background thread. It may be when they send messsages and there's no message loop to process them, there's a delay. Or maybe there's some marshalling back to the right SynchronizationContext happening that takes the time. Not sure.

A profiler that profiles your own code and .NET Framework code should tell you though.

```
public string SelectedRtf
    {
      get
      {
        this.ForceHandleCreate();
        return this.StreamOut(32770);
      }
      set
      {
        this.ForceHandleCreate();
        if (value == null)
          value = "";
        this.StreamIn(value, 32770);
      }
    }

private void StreamIn(string str, int flags)
{
  if (str.Length == 0)
  {
    if ((32768 & flags) != 0)
    {
      this.SendMessage(771, 0, 0);
      this.ProtectedError = false;
    }
    else
      this.SendMessage(12, 0, "");
  }
  else
  {
    int length = str.IndexOf(char.MinValue);
    if (length != -1)
      str = str.Substring(0, length);
    byte[] buffer = (flags & 16) == 0 ? Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str) : Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
    this.editStream = (Stream) new MemoryStream(buffer.Length);
    this.editStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    this.editStream.Position = 0L;
    this.StreamIn(this.editStream, flags);
  }
}

private void StreamIn(Stream data, int flags)
{
  if ((flags & 32768) == 0)
    System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef((object) this, this.Handle), 1079, 0, new System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.CHARRANGE());
  try
  {
    this.editStream = data;
    if ((flags & 2) != 0)
    {
      long position = this.editStream.Position;
      byte[] numArray = new byte[RichTextBox.SZ_RTF_TAG.Length];
      this.editStream.Read(numArray, (int) position, RichTextBox.SZ_RTF_TAG.Length);
      string @string = Encoding.Default.GetString(numArray);
      if (!RichTextBox.SZ_RTF_TAG.Equals(@string))
        throw new ArgumentException(System.Windows.Forms.SR.GetString("InvalidFileFormat"));
      this.editStream.Position = position;
    }
    System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.EDITSTREAM editstream = new System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.EDITSTREAM();
    int num1 = (flags & 16) == 0 ? 5 : 9;
    int num2 = (flags & 2) == 0 ? num1 | 16 : num1 | 64;
    editstream.dwCookie = (IntPtr) num2;
    editstream.pfnCallback = new System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.EditStreamCallback(this.EditStreamProc);
    this.SendMessage(1077, 0, int.MaxValue);
    if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
    {
      System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.EDITSTREAM64 editstreaM64 = this.ConvertToEDITSTREAM64(editstream);
      System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef((object) this, this.Handle), 1097, flags, editstreaM64);
      editstream.dwError = this.GetErrorValue64(editstreaM64);
    }
    else
      System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef((object) this, this.Handle), 1097, flags, editstream);
    this.UpdateMaxLength();
    if (this.GetProtectedError())
      return;
    if (editstream.dwError != 0)
      throw new InvalidOperationException(System.Windows.Forms.SR.GetString("LoadTextError"));
    this.SendMessage(185, -1, 0);
    this.SendMessage(186, 0, 0);
  }
  finally
  {
    this.editStream = (Stream) null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Won't fit in a comment, so I'll post an answer.

I haven't used WinForms for ages, but shouldn't WinForms throw an error for accesing a UI element from non-UI code? I remember having to do a bunch of `this.Invoke` stuff, but maybe the backgroundworker handles things differently.

Anyway, my guess is that the main chunk of the extra time is going to syncrhonizing with the UI thread inorder to access the RichTextBox. Bring out the good old stopwatch and measure your code to see where the botleneck is.

I wonder if it would be faster to seperate text into chunks and use multiple threads - quad core work ;) - to find all the matches and then in the end go to the UI thread, iterate through all the matches and highlight the text.

It should also be possible to only highlight text on the visible area of screen and when the user scrolls to higlight further text...